# Cannot get .after command to work in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have searched, and tried using the .after command in Tkinter in my application, but nothing I do solves the issue. No matter what i try to do, the 2 boxes that I am trying to delay both come up at the same time.

```
submenu.add_command(label="View High Score", command=lambda: check_hs_file())

def check_hs_file():
    hs_file = 'highscore.txt'
    PATH = ('highscore.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(PATH):
        get_hs_as_int()
        #go to main function
    else:
        with open(hs_file, 'w') as hs_file:
            hs_file.write('0')
        if os.path.isfile(PATH):
            toplevel1 = Toplevel()
            toplevel1.title("High Score!")
            toplevel1.focus_set()
            hs_textbox = Text(toplevel1, height=2, width=50)
            hs_textbox.pack()
            hs_textbox.insert(END, "You don't have a high score yet.. Creating file!\n")
            get_hs_as_int()
        else:
            toplevel = Toplevel()
            toplevel.title("High Score!")
            toplevel.focus_set()
            hs_textbox = Text(toplevel, height=2, width=50)
            hs_textbox.pack()
            hs_textbox.after(3000)
            hs_textbox.insert(END, "Something went wrong, we could not create a file to keep your high score!")

def get_hs_as_int():
    hs_file = 'highscore.txt'
    with open(hs_file, 'r') as hs_file:
        high_score = hs_file.read()
        high_score = int(high_score)
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.after(4000)
    toplevel.title("High Score!")
    toplevel.focus_set()
    hs_textbox = Text(toplevel, height=2, width=50)
    hs_textbox.pack()
    hs_textbox.insert(END, "Your high score is: {}".format(high_score))
```

Again, the box printing the high score, and the one checking to see if there is a high score, come up at the same time. No matter where I add the .after to my code. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Its difficult to test your code, as it depends on many files, etc. Some dummy, simple code demonstrating the core of the problem would be useful, so that we can run it, test it, amend it and hopefully provide answer.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

The usual syntax for `Tk.Widget.after` takes a callback function as an argument.

So, to use a small snippet as an example, you might write:

```
def method(...):
    ... # calculate the meaning of life

    def callback():
        print("I'm called later!")

    self.after(10, callback)  # execute callback() after 10s
```

---

More commonly, what you do is define another function or method in the class or module, and then pass off to that after a specified time.

So, for example, if you want to show a popup shortly after your window appears, you might do something like:

```
class Controller():
    def __init__(self, master):
        # perform some initial setup

        master.after(5, self.finalise)  # run self.finalise() after 5s

        # do some more setup

    def finalise(self):
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Called later', 'Yippeeeeeee!')
```